# /catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, bash, bashrc

How can i remove this?

```
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/pro/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/pro/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/pro/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/pro/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/pro/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: What you trying to do? When these lines are coming up?

Comment: i installed ROS when i remove ros file, i got this messages

Comment: I think, there are some unnecessary lines in your `~/.bashrc` file. Please, `gedit ~/.bashrc &` and paste here, as plain text, last 10 rows of it.

Comment: okay i'll try it

Comment: source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source/opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
source/opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash

Comment: thank you ! I typed gedit ~/.bashrc  and delete every lines about ROS

Comment: I mean put them in the question :) Whatever, if you delete them, these messages will disappear.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/tour :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has left some unnecessary lines in your `~/.bashrc` file. `gedit ~/.bashrc` find and delete them.

This one `source/opt/ros/jade/setup.bash` was added by the command, that you typed on the screenshot: `$ echo "source/opt/ros/jade/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: i solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this issue, but I had a different solution. I'm using `zsh` and I needed to change:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

to

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.zsh
```

in my `.zshrc`